# In C what does this line do:

Tags: c

```
printf("\n%12.6f%12.6f%12.6f", R[1], LS[1], LAMBDA);
```

The `R` is an array of floats, `LS` is also an array of floats, and `LAMBDA` is a single float variable.

I'm trying to convert a program over to Java but I cannot figure out what this line is trying to do (I am not experienced in C at all).

Comment: It would take you 2 seconds to find that if you search on google, just `printf c manual`.

Answer (score 1):

The [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) function prints to stdout, which is usually the console, and uses a particular variable-replacement syntax in strings - what you're looking at is thus a format string. Breaking it down:

- `\n` : newline
- `%12.6f` : next variable,

  - width 12 -- Padded with spaces to make the string exactly 12 characters if it's not already
  - precision 6 -- Six digits after the decimal point
  - in decimal floating point format
- +2 more iterations of this

The array lookup syntax is the same as in Java, so it's looking up the second (because zero-based indexing) element in R and LS.

Comment: I guess the majority of my question would be... What is this: "\n%12.6f%12.6f%12.6f"

Comment: Added this to my comment, as I needed to take a moment to lookup the exact specifications. I've also updated the included link to a more descriptive page

Answer (score 0):

It just print these value to stdout, in float number format with specified format.
More details can be found at [`printf()`](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tiny test program, and its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float R[2] = {1./7. * 10000, 2./7. * 10000};
    float LS[2] = {3./7. *10000, 4/7. * 10000};
    float LAMBDA = 5/7. *10000;
    printf("BEFORE");
    printf("\n%12.6f%12.6f%12.6f", R[1], LS[1], LAMBDA);
    printf("AFTER\n");
}
```

BEFORE
 2857.142822 5714.285645 7142.856934AFTER

So, a newline, then all on one line, with each number taking up 12 spaces, R[1], LS[1], and LAMBDA, printed to 6 digits of accuracy. Then, no newline, so they must want something else to happen on the line line after.